# No TwinView option in nvidia-settings

Tags: gentoo, nvidia

Good Morning,

I cannot find the TwinView options in nvidia-settings; is it gone? I tried enabling it manually in xorg.conf but then the server won't start.

Nvidia Driver: 340.76
X: 1.16.4
Kernel: 3.18.11
Dist: Gentoo

If, for whatever reason, it's gone is there a way to enable the same functionality? I.e two screens whereby you can move applications between then and maximize them without it filling both monitors?